# How to Create a Select Font Drop Down List With a Preview?

Tags: html, css

I would l like to create a select drop down list to be able to select a font. In this list, I would like each font option to be shown in that style as a preview of the font.

```
<select>
    <option class="Times-New-Roman" value="Times-New-Roman">Times New Roman</option>
    <option class="Verdana" value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
    <option value="Comic-Sans-MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
    <option value="WildWest">WildWest</option>
    <option value="Bedrock">Bedrock</option>
</select>
```

Above is a basic drop down box, of which each font type has it's own class name, however cannot seem to work out  how to make it so that each class name has it's own font which will show in the drop down list.

Thank you for any time spent in helping find a solution.

Best Regards,
Tim

Comment: Maybe something like this? http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/reinventing-a-drop-down-with-css-and-jquery/ I have created fiddle from this example (http://jsfiddle.net/h7YqN/), look at the last option from drop down, there is Comic Sans MS. Try to avoid styling of "select" element, you can't do that in every browser. Instead, use this code or any another code to reproduce effect of drop down. You can also extend this code, and apply values to hidden inputs, if there is need to get selected value via form.

Comment: Just remember that you can't redesign "select" list. You must use some JavaSrcipt or jQuery to simulate "select" list with "li" or similiar. There is a lot of scripts to do that.

Answer (score 4):

try format like below.

```
<select>
    <option style="font-family:'Times New Roman';" class="Times-New-Roman" value="Times-New-Roman">Times New Roman</option>
    <option style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;" class="Verdana" value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
```